# npm extraneous package meaning. Usability of extraneous packages

Tags: debugging, npm, dependencies, package.json

Can a npm *extraneous* error mean something other than the fact that 
the package.json file doesn't contain it as a dependency?

Is there any use for extraneous packages? If not why npm install things without explicitly putting them into `package.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Extraneous** is not an actual error. As you said, it just means that the package is not explicitly defined (**and**, I suppose, that is not directly related to the dependency tree).

Can happen when the dependency has already been installed globally (`npm install -g <package>`).
Or (happened to me) when using a "Github URL"-dependency to a repository that, in the same way, has another "Github URL"-dependency in its `package.json`.

I am not sure if that is an intended behaviour or a lack of support for nested "Github URL"-dependencies.